# How to add Contact List data into PhoneGap ListView

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, listview, cordova

I have a javascript function which will read the device ContactList and add them into a javascript array.In my HTML page i have taken a `listview`.Now as per my requirement i have to add these array data into the listview by jquery dynamically which i am not able to do .I am not able to see anything on the screen of the mobile on launching the app..

Here is my javascript code to read from Mobile's contact list..

```
        function onDeviceReady() {

         // specify contact search criteria
         var options = new ContactFindOptions();
         options.filter="";          // empty search string returns all contacts
         options.multiple=true;      // return multiple results
         filter = ["displayName"];   // return contact.displayName field

          // find contacts
          navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
         }

         var names = [];

        // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
        //
      function onSuccess(contacts) {
        for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
           if (contacts[i].displayName) {  // many contacts don't have displayName
        names.push(contacts[i].displayName);
        }
        }
           alert('contacts loaded');

        }
```

and here is my HTML listview..

```
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="c">

<div data-role="content">

<div id="header" class="header">
    <h1>Contact Directory</h1>
</div>

    <ul data-role="listview"  id="contactlist" data-theme="a">

    </ul>

</div>
</div>
```

So, My question is how can i add the array values into the listview by jquery dynamically..
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of ways, but here is one way.

Create a simple string variable to hold your LIs.
Loop over names and append to the string <li> + names[x] + </li> where X is your loop counter.
Use jQuery to get the UL dom and then do .html(s) where s is your string.

Basically you are injecting <li>...</li><li>...</li> into your UL.

The last step is to refresh the list view so jQuery displays it correctly. This is done with the refresh API, defined here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/#method-refresh